# Show the map $f(x)=\frac12 (x+1/x)$ has an attractive fixed point in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

From numerical test, I know $x=1$ is an attractive fixed point of the function
$$
f(x)=\frac12 \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right),
$$
on $(0,\infty)$.
Is there a way to prove it?

Since
$$
f'(x)=\frac12\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right),
$$
then
$$
|f'(x)| < 1,
$$
on $[1,\infty)$, and Banach contraction principle gives the result.
But how to proceed for $(0,1)$?
Let $a_0 \in (0,1)$ and choose 
$$
0< \epsilon < a_0,
$$
then the derivative is bounded on $(\epsilon,\infty)$.
But I don't see how to build a contraction on $(\epsilon,\infty)$, which gives the result.
I tried
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{M}f(x),
$$
with
$$
M=\sup\{x\in(\epsilon,\infty):|f'(x)|\}+1,
$$
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Notice that $f(1/x) = f(x)$, so what happens to $x \in (0,1)$ after one iterations?

Comment: Iterations of $f$ are what you get from applying Newton's method to finding the positive root of $g(x)=x^2-1$.  Here is a link to a proof that Newton's method will always give a sequence converging to the root, for a class of functions that includes $g$: http://planetmath.org/newtonsmethodworksforconvexrealfunctions

Comment: For this particular case, the iterate of $f$ can be expressed in a closed form: $$f^{\circ n}(x) = \underbrace{f\circ f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{n\text{ times}}(x) = \frac{1+\alpha^{2^n}}{1-\alpha^{2^n}} \quad\text{ where }\quad \alpha = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$$For any $x \in (0,\infty)$, $$|\alpha| < 1 \implies\lim_{n\to\infty} f^{\circ n}(x) = 1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the inequality $x+\frac{1}{x}\ge 2$, which can be proved many ways. For example, we can note that $\left(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2\ge 0$. Or else we can quote AM/GM.

**Remark:** The fixed point is in fact *very* attractive, since the derivative there is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f(x)=f\left(\frac 1 x\right)$, once proven for $x > 1$ that $f^{(n)}(x)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$, then you get it for $x\in(0,1)$ "for free".